# 1-rep user with 24 answer upvotes plus Suffrage/Vox Populi?

Tags: discussion, bug, badges, users

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639785/rekha-indianmoney-com) has <strike>24</strike> 23 answer upvotes in the current month, the month in which they joined. The user has both the vote-cap badges (which require 30 and 40 votes respectively). The user only has 1 rep and has never had any more than 1 rep in their history (nor are they suspended), so how could the user cast any upvotes in the first place (given that you need 15 rep to upvote)?

What's up with this?

Comment: "The user only has 1 rep and has never had any more than 1 rep in their history" Wrong: on Mar 6, they got 20 points, yesterday they lost them again.

Comment: @glglgl: It shows that now, but it didn't before. (I would have taken a screenshot if I thought it would change under me.) I checked, and neither the graph nor the list showed any entries at all. ... why this is now glitching differently, I don't know.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This user appears to be either a sock puppet or a member of a voting ring. The user bumped a two-year-old question with what was essentially an abridged copy of the accepted answer, and their answer was then upvoted enough times to gain them voting privileges. The answer was deleted by the review process — no spam flags were involved here, although hilariously the user's name makes them look like a spammer.

I think I'm going to let this one sit around for a bit while we figure out how to handle the situation cleanly. **Update:** it's been dealt with.

As for Suffrage and Vox Populi, I can only agree with Andy's speculation that some of the posts they voted on have since been deleted. However I'm not sure how exactly the vote counts on a user profile are determined, so I can't confirm anything.

Comment: Question to poke the devs with (or investigate known sock puppets that have low vote counts and can be investigated as a mod since you likely have more insight into this): How are reversed (not deleted) votes from serial voting (or undoing a vote?) counted.

Comment: Any more details on how the user was dealt with, or does that not particularly matter?

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: In general, we deal with voting rings by invalidating votes, removing sock puppets and messaging/suspending the users involved depending on severity.

Comment: @BoltClock: How many of these voting rings exist/have been dealt with? This is the first I've heard of them, so I'm wondering if you're like Batman, fighting off all these ring leaders that the average citizen never hears about, every night, or if it's something that comes up once in a bluemoon, and each mod only has to be an unsung hero beating up the members of a ring, once in their life.

Answer (score 9):

This answer is making a large assumption since non-moderators can't see deleted posts on a user's profile:

Based on the user's name, my assumption is that the user was hit with spam flags. Each [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/186281) that receives 6 spam flags nets the first revision author -100 reputation.

How did the user get the permissions to upvote? I suspect that the most likely order of events is:

- User contributed enough content to garner those privileges.
- They then submitted spam. Those were then flagged and removed.
- Either the previously good content was edited and flagged as spam or all of their content ended up getting removed as spam after closer investigations.

If this occurs within a single day, we wouldn't see those reputation changes. To us, it's a net 0 change for the day, which doesn't show on their public reputation graph.

Comment: That seems plausible. I'm used to seeing a lot on the rep graphs, so seeing a big fat nothing is pretty startling.

Comment: @Roombatron5000, they may have voted on now deleted posts.

Comment: While eloquently stated, assumptions aren't fact. It might be better to not make assumptions (particularly those related to things like spam) and let others who have actual factual knowledge of the situation provide answers. (Particularly relevant since @BoltClock's answer clearly states that no spam flags were involved.)

Comment: Of note, if the post was flagged as spam and deleted as spam, I *believe* it also comes with a -100 rep penalty.  I'll also point to my own profile for the voting on now deleted posts.  It shows I have 7002 down votes on the [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/289086/michaelt), but when I look at my votes > down votes, I only see 1716 votes cast meaning there are a bit over 5000 down votes on now deleted posts.  Profile vote count *doesn't* disappear when votes are deleted. Now, the vote might have been *reversed* (serial voting script anyone) which may be a different process.

Comment: @MichaelT thanks for that, I didn't realize that's what the discrepancy represents.